# @Url.Action dinamico error C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

En una tabla estoy guardado menus y su "path", tengo un `view` que lee ese menu cuando se recarga la pagina, actualmente tengo problemas con este dato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trato leer el siguiente url asi:

```
 var url = n.url;
 if (url == "")
    {
       url = "";
       <a href="@Url.Action(url, url)" class="dropdown-item" data-key="t-calendar">@n.Nombre</a>

    }
 else if (url.Contains("Detalle"))
  {
     //string url1 = GetUntilOrEmpty(n.url, "/");
     string [] url1 = url.Split('/');
     string url2 = url1[1]+"/"+url1[2];
     <a href="@Url.Action(url2, url1)" class="dropdown-item" data-key="t-calendar">@n.Nombre</a>
  }
  else
  {
     <a href="@Url.Action(url, url)" class="dropdown-item" data-key="t-calendar">@n.Nombre</a>
  }
```

El problema lo tengo en el `else if`,mi controlador es `ListadoReportes`, cuando pasa el `split` realmente lo separa por el "/":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el Url.Action toma actionName, controllerName, por lo tanto estoy poniendo:

```
@Url.Action("Detalle/1", "ListadoReportes")
```

Pero esta tomando el controlador donde este cargado en ese momento, por ejemplo, si estoy en el controlador `Home`, el toma la siguiente URL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://localhost:44399/Home/Detalle/1?Length=3&LongLength=3&Rank=1&SyncRoot=System.String%5B%5D&IsReadOnly=False&IsFixedSize=True&IsSynchronized=False

Como hago para que tome el campo que le estoy pasando si agregarle lo que esta demas o el controlador equivocado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que estas asignando url2, url1 a @Url.Action()

```
<a href="@Url.Action(url2, url1)" class="dropdown-item" data-key="t-calendar">@n.Nombre</a>
```

Pero en la parte de tu código tienes:

```
string [] url1 = url.Split('/');
string url2 = url1[1]+"/"+url1[2];
```

Donde se ve que url1 es un arreglo de string. Entonces le estas asignando un arreglo a @Url.Action().

Intenta separar el valor del controlador. Algo como esto.

```
string [] url1 = url.Split('/');
string url2 = url1[1]+"/"+url1[2];
string controller = url1[0];
<a href="@Url.Action(url2, controller)" class="dropdown-item" data-key="t-calendar">@n.Nombre</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

En la vista:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(url2, url1)" class="dropdown-item" data-key="t-calendar">@n.Nombre</a>
```

Sucede que para pasar parámetros, se deben especificar de la siguiente manera:

```
@Url.Action("Action","Controller", new { parametroA = "ValorA", parametroB = ValorB})
```

Por lo tanto, en tu código, estaría algo así:

```
@Url.Action("Detalle","ListadoReportes", new { id = "1" })
```

Si tienes paciencia y 4 horas 4 minutos 4 segundos, mira este workshop que hice sobre ASPnet MVC: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY contiene los fundamentos necesarios, es un resumen de un curso de lo que fue la Microsoft Virtual Academy de un path de 27 horas aprox.

Mayor información: [Documentación Oficial ASPnet MVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)